# grep function from within makefile

Tags: git, shell, makefile

I am trying to run a `SonarQube` analysis for my `C` code. I want to run the analysis as a make target. I want to add a property to get the branch name by using git commands

I tried to build the git command to get the branch name (also covered the condition when it is in detached `HEAD` state).

This particular line in my Makefile is causing the problem

```
SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS = -Dsonar.branch.name=$(shell git ls-remote --heads origin | grep $(git rev-parse HEAD) | cut -d / -f3,4) -Dsonar.projectVersion=$(shell date +%Y%m%d%H%M-${USER})
```

The error I am getting is:

> Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
>   Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Can anybody help me understand what is wrong with my syntax? I have tried a few more things like double quoting the command, using $$ and changing the paranthesis around but it does not behave as expected.

Comment: Did you check if ```git rev-parse HEAD``` returns data? In case it evaluates into an empty string (no whitespace characters), grep will show you the error message that you've written in your answer.

Comment: I believe you need to escape dollar signs in shell code as `$$` within makefiles.

Comment: That's quite a complex statement. Try breaking it down into simpler statements; show us the simplest one that fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS = -Dsonar.branch.name=$(shell git ls-remote --heads origin | grep $(git rev-parse HEAD) | cut -d / -f3,4) -Dsonar.projectVersion=$(shell date +%Y%m%d%H%M-${USER})
```

you have

```
| grep $(git rev-parse HEAD) |
```

and Make thinks that `git` is a make function, just like it thinks `shell` is a make function. But unlike `shell`, the Make function `git` doesn't exist so it comes out empty and so the above pipe amounts to

```
| grep |
```

Which is why you're getting grep's usage message.

You need to replace it with

```
| grep $(shell git rev-parse HEAD) |
```

An alternative would be to have the shell execute git instead of having Make execute it:

```
| grep $$(git rev-parse HEAD) |
```

But that's less readable.

Comment: The problem with `$(shell git rev-parse HEAD)` is that it gets evaluated at the time the Makefile is parsed.

Comment: While true, `HEAD` doesn't usually change during the execution of `make`, although maybe that's required for SonarQube, I'm not familiar with it.